# Magento custom category widget not appearing on stage server

Tags: php, magento, widget, categories, custom-widgets

I followed this (first comment), 
[magento - category name and image in static block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889747/magento-category-name-and-image-in-static-block/10894043#10894043) to create a simple widget to display the category image and title from a static block on a CMS page. It works fine on my local MAMP version of Magento Enterprise 1.13.0.2. It's not working however on the stage / test environment Magento 1.13.1.0. (ubuntu).

It doesn't error, it's as though it's ignoring the template file (info.phtml). When I reverted to the default theme I realised I had to copy the template files to the default enterprise folder to get it to work but it did (local version). I have made sure that the template folders are in each of the themes, base, enterprise (default), MyTheme (default (which is enterprise default) & (MyTheme / MyThemeVariant)).

The only setting / configuration that appears to be different between the local and the stage is that pretty url's aren't working on the local. I have looked into the htaccess and it still isn't resolved. On both versions the native Category link Widget isn't working but i'm not sure if that is relevant.

I have disabled any extensions turned the cache off and cleared the index. Still nothing.

I have been looking for the answer, retracing my steps, altering and changing back any setting(s) I think may be relevant for 3 days now so i'm well stuck. Anything anyone can offer to try I will give it a go.

Comment: Are you saying that the widget works perfectly in the back end on the staging server? You can add it to CMS content, yes? But when you look at the front end there is no widget displayed, implying a problem with the info.phtml file? (but this is Magento so it doesn't mean there is a problem with the phtml file). Enterprise has a couple of different caches I think (standard and full-page) and your staging web server might have some cacheing too.

Comment: Thanks for your message Malachy, sorry for the late reply, I have just seen this. You have understood the situation correctly. I disabled all the caches under cache management. Are there other caches I need to look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that "Block" php file's first letter was lowercase. I changed it from info.php to Info.php and now everything works as expected.

This has been the single most frustrating investigation yet into Magento. The only thing I hope is that it saves someone a whole load of pain.

Answer (score 0):

So in Magento Enterprise there is also a full page cache that you can access via the Magento Admin here : System->Configuration->System->advanced->External full page cache settings.

On the page System->Cache management, as well as disabling all the caches you should flush the Magento Cache and the Cache Storage.

You might have a 'cache' called Redis or APC, but I don't think that affects .phtml output. and if you can access the Widget in the back end I don;t think those items are the problem.

Your webserver might have a full page cache such as Varnish but I don't know how to use it or turn it on or off.

Theoretically your webserver headers might be saying 'this page doesn't update so internet providers can store local copies in their caches' - but I would be astonished if that was the case (inspect your header and inspect the `Cache-control` `Expires` and `Last-modifed` headers if you want to eliminate this possibility).

Your browser might have it's own little cache (which you can clear from your browser settings).

If it isn't a cache problem, in my experience `.phtml` files get skipped if they have PHP errors in them but you have it working on your local dev server. Could it be a file permission issue? Could it be a setting in the widget on your server that is not handled by your widgets .phtml? As alast resort, try changing your widget .phtml to a really simple file like `<?php echo('test PHP output'); ?>` and see if that renders - try putting the widget on different pages (ie new pages that won't be cached anywhere) and see if that get's everything through.

Could you have a namespace conflict with another module? Eg an XML file is changing your widget block XML name that sets the .phtml template? Does your widget.xml file declare `<supported_blocks>...</supported_blocks>` which might be excluding the block into which you are trying to render the widget?

What else? You mentioned this widget displays category information: Are you referring to a category that exists on your staging server? It will probably have a different category ID than your dev server and / or check the category is visible in the website and store.

Okay, I think I am out of ideas now.